# Python/Aptana List Issue

Tags: python, aptana3

I have been trying to figure out what is wrong with my Python/Aptana configuration.
I keep typing in a basic list and running it with no result.  The console shows nothing after I run the program and no errors are posting but the console is empty.
I am using `Python 3.3.0` and `Aptana Studio 3`.

My interpreter is 
`C:\Python33python.exe` and my PYTHONPATH is

`System libs>C:\Python33.dlls>C:\Python33.lib>C:\Python33>C:\Python33\lib\site-packages`.

My simple program:

```
aList = [1,"john","Craig","car",3,6]
aList
aList[2]
```

I looked everywhere including stackoverflow and can't find an answer.  I know this is basic but please help.  My PYTHONPATH must be wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: it's PYTHONPATH, not PYONPATH

Answer (score 1):

Not sure anything is wrong with your configuration, but your python code is not returning anything.  If you are trying to see the output of aList[2]:

```
aList = [1,"john","Craig","car",3,6]
aList
print aList[2]
```